# SBT with Maven Central - get rid of Scala version in artifact url

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, maven-central

I am trying to use in my `Scala` project `Java` library which is on `Maven Central`. While resolving this dependency, `SBT` appends `Scala version` to the repository url which obviously does not exist in such a format. Can I somehow disable appending Scala version for this specific artifact?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, use `%` instead of `%%` before the artifact specifier for your dependency. The `%%` notation indicates that the library is dependent on the Scala runtime version, yours is not.

Comment: It's before the artifact specifier, not the version specifier.

Comment: Thanks, but I still could not find it `unresolved dependency: com.yahoo.util#myProject;0.16.0-SNAPSHOT: not found` , what's missing? and what is `;` doing?